# Movie about a cop fighting an organisation that uses cyborg ninjas

Tags: story-identification, movie, cyborg

I saw this live-action movie in 1997, could be an 80s or 90s movie.

A cop is trying to fight criminal organisation that uses ninjas. They start using cyborg tech to transform the ninjas into killing machines. They are made in big tubes filled with fluid and towards the end of the movie the cop decides to undergo the procedure to become the same as the ninjas to win.

Its not *Cyborg*, or other obvious movies I can find.

Comment: Just to be clear, this is a live-action movie?  Sadly I don't see anything promising on the [TVTropes page](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CyberNinja).

Comment: Did somebody say ["Robot Ninjas"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TzL626WF090)?

Comment: @DavidW Yes you're correct, it is live action.